# React component doesn't re-render after Redux store update

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have a React issue. My component `NavBar` doesn't rerender `points` value after updating it in store with form. I want to rerender component so it can get new `points` value with `useSelector` hook and then display it in button on the page.

Here is my Redux initialState code:

```js
const initialState = {
  points: '3100',
  rewards: [
    {...}              
  ],
};
```

My pointsRedux file:

```js
// selectors
export const getAllPoints = state => state.points;

// actions
const createActionName = actionName => `app/points/${actionName}`;
const UPDATE_POINTS = createActionName('UPDATE_POINTS');

// action creators
export const updatePoints = payload => ({ type: UPDATE_POINTS, payload });

// subreducer
const pointsReducer = (statePart = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_POINTS:
      console.log('redux', action.payload);
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return statePart;
  };
};

export default pointsReducer;
```

My form component (without imports):

```js
// other imports
import { getAllPoints, updatePoints } from '../../../redux/pointsRedux';

const AddPointsWidget = () => {

  const currentPoints = useSelector(getAllPoints);
  const [newPoints, setNewPoints] = useState(currentPoints);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(updatePoints(newPoints));
  };

  return (
    <form className={styles.AddPointsWidget} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <>...</>  
      <SubmitButton>
        {'Zmień punkty'}
      </SubmitButton>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And NavBar component which doesn't rerender after submit form:

```js
import { getAllPoints } from '../../../redux/pointsRedux';

const NavBar = () => {
  const points = useSelector(getAllPoints);

  return (
    <nav className={styles.NavBar}>
      <>...</>
      <PointsButton
        location={'NavBar'}
        amount={points}
        clickFunction={openPopUp}
      />
      <>...</>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

I would like to force rerender of `NavBar` with `points` value displayed in button after submitting form with value given to input without reloading page.
I tried `useEffect` hook and `useNavigate` from Router but can't fix this.
Do you guys have any idea how can I make it to work properly?

Repo on GitHub below:
https://github.com/jerzy-jarczynski/react-rewards-app

I tried `useEffect` to refresh points in `NavBar` components after `currentPoints` from Redux `useSelector` change. I tried also to `useNavigate` to switch to `'/'` after submitting form.

I am expecting to see updated `points` value in my `NavBar` component inside the button without reloading page.

Comment: You never call `setNewPoints` so `newPoints` always have the initial value

Comment: `action.payload` is always 3100 as you see in the console log

Comment: You may need to [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] since from what we can tell the `newPoints` reference never changes and so a React rerender will never be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with version of React render
index.js before (not working):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import store from './redux/store'
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/normalize.scss';
import './styles/global.scss';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Fixing bugs with lower version of React render
index.js after (working)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import store from './redux/store'
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/normalize.scss';
import './styles/global.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```